# Google play subscription and free trial for mobile app automatically cancels/ends

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, subscription, trial

We have a new application recently released on Google Play. The initial group of testers subscribed for a free 60-day trial. Over the past month, their subscription has been automatically removed/ended multiple times making them resubscribe. We posted some updated versions since they were first subscribed. Has anybody else experienced a similar issue with a trial/subscription automatically ending or being canceled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Google Play Support:

If you use the Google Play Billing Library version 2.0 or newer, you must acknowledge all purchases within three days. Failure to properly acknowledge purchases results in those purchases being refunded.

Google Play supports purchasing products from inside of your app (in-app) or outside of your app (out-of-app). In order for Google Play to ensure a consistent purchase experience regardless of where the user purchases your product, you must acknowledge all purchases that have a "Success" state received through the Google Play Billing Library as soon as possible after granting entitlement to the user. If you do not acknowledge a purchase within three days, the user automatically receives a refund, and Google Play revokes the purchase. For pending transactions, the three-day window does not apply when the purchase is in a "Pending" state. Instead, it starts when the purchase has moved to the "Success" state.

Here are some specific resources on the Android Developers site:

Acknowledge a purchase (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#acknowledge)

Google Play Billing Library 2.0 Release notes (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_releases_notes#release-2_0)

Purchases must be acknowledged within three days (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_releases_notes#2_0_acknowledge)

API guides (http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)

Android Studio & SDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Also, you can find Developer Support communities listed here: http://developer.android.com/support.html